# Opengl ES Application works in simulator, but not on phone

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios-simulator

I have created a simlpe Opengl ES application, a sphere bouncing back and forth in a room. When running on simulator it works fine. I have configured the simulator to be HW 3.0, from xCode I chose Simulator - 3.0|Debug. Since I only have a 3G, not 3Gs, I assume this should give the same result?

What can the reason be and how the heck am I going to debug this kind of problem? I don't know where to go from here... Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I enabled GL_COLOR_ARRAY but didn't use color arrays. This caused the error. I don't understand why, but removing "glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);" solved it. It also explains my secondary problem why my sphere were having strange kind of colors, it now looks nice again...

Furthert, it also explains (I think, please correct me if I am wrong) why glGetError didn't caught any error where I thought the problem occured (it always happened at the same line in my code, but probably unrelated to that row).